# How to properly initialize GameCenter login without interrupting gameplay

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

I am working on a game that has `Game Center` integration. When they first open the game I check to see if they are already authorized with `Game Center`. If not, I show the login that GC provides.

The issue is, that if a user is not authenticated, and they open the app, then quickly tap the screen to start the game, the GC authentication controller will pop up in the middle of playing the game.

```
// Login the User
GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {

    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
        // Allow user to start game?
    } else if(viewController) {
        // Allow user to login to Game Center
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        // Allow user to start game?
    }
};
```

I realize that I could only allow game play if they are connected to GC, but what if they don't have internet access, or they don't want to use GC?

What is the best solution here?

Answer (score 1):

The test to see if a player is authenticated can take several seconds. What you will want to do is enable a state system in your app to be able to detect if they are currently playing the game, if they are you will defer the game center login till later, if they aren't you can show the login controls immediately.

Comment: Is this the normal practice with games?

Comment: Most games pop login during gameplay while actively pausing, which is the other option.

Answer (score 0):

I used to pause the game and show the login, but I have an app that the first time you start it, I want users to start interacting straight away, without login prompt interruptions.

Because I'm using SpriteKit, the way I'm deciding if I have to defer the login is by checking the current active scene. If I have to wait, I store a temporal function to continue later.

The code looks like this,

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  var attemptAuthentication: (()->())?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    gameCenterAuthenticate()
    return true
  }

  fileprivate func gameCenterAuthenticate() {
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController?, error : Error?) -> Void in
        if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated {
            // auth successful
            self.enableGameCenterForPlayer(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer())
            NSLog("GC: Logged in")
        } else if let vc = viewController {
            //self.pauseGame() // no need to pause in this case
            if let _ = self.getCurrentScene() as? MainSelectionScene {
                NSLog("GC: Attempting login")
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated:true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                NSLog("GC: Deferring login for later")
                self.attemptAuthentication = { [weak self] in
                    self?.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated:true, completion: nil)
                    self?.attemptAuthentication = nil
                }
            }
        } else {
            // auth failed, provide gracefull fallback
            self.disableGameCenter()
            self.resumeGame()
            NSLog("GC: Login failed")
        }
        if let err = error {
            NSLog("GC: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

And in my game selection scene,

```
class MainSelectionScene: SKScene {
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    appDelegate.attemptAuthentication?()
  }
  // ...    
}
```

Not sure this is the best way, because I couldn't find any example of this in Apple's documentation, but it seems like a simple and straightforward solution.